# Pivot table based on monthly sales using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe df having sales by month:

```
customer product   month     revenue

     sam       A      2021-11      221
    
     tim       A      2021-12      220
    
     mi.       B      2021-10     213
    
     harry     A      2011-11    210
    
     eric.     A.      2021-10    213
```

Need the output:

For Product A:

```
customer product   2021-10.   2021-11.  2021-12
     
 sam       A        0            221      0  

 tim       A        0             0      220

 harry     A        0            210      0
 
 erIc     A.      213            0       0
```

the format of month is period(M).Any way to do this in python using pivot_table function.There are lot of products so i need to specify the product name in the code.

Comment: ?? Any help !!!

Comment: any suggestion or any references?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["customer","product","month","revenue"])
data=data.append({"customer":"eric.","product":20,"month":"2011-10","revenue":213},ignore_index=True)
data=data.append({"customer":"harry","product":20,"month":"2011-11","revenue":210},ignore_index=True)
data=data.append({"customer":"tim","product":20,"month":"2011-12","revenue":220},ignore_index=True)
data=data.append({"customer":"sam","product":20,"month":"2021-11","revenue":221},ignore_index=True)
data=data.append({"customer":"mi","product":30,"month":"2021-10","revenue":213},ignore_index=True)
    
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(data,values=["revenue"],index=["customer","product"],columns=["month"],fill_value=0,aggfunc=np.sum)
    
pivot_df_filtered = pivot_df.query("product == 20")
```

[image]

Comment: I need to include product in the code something like where product=A

Comment: you can filter based on product code

Comment: Can please add below that line

Comment: getting error invalid syntax when filtering

Comment: Could you please paste the error ? May be some typo ?

Comment: The product name is numerical number 20, getting syntax error: Invalid syntax

Comment: Ah ! Gotcha. In your example , you had given product as a` string` value. You just need to change the query to  `pivot_df.query("product == 20")`

Comment: still getting the error. Its 20.0

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: @tim83 : Please check the answer. I updated the data frame and queried as you mentioned.

Comment: product is in float64

Comment: there is issue with column names,  can we rename it.

Comment: yeah sure. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-rename-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Can you add a code to rename columns to single names. Its showing error because of multiframe index

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help:

```
g_data = data.groupby(['product','month','customer'])['revenue'].sum().unstack('month').fillna(0)

>>> g_data
'''
month             2021-10  2021-11  2021-12
product customer                           
A       eric.       213.0      0.0      0.0
        harry         0.0    210.0      0.0
        sam           0.0    221.0      0.0
        tim           0.0      0.0    220.0
B       mi.         213.0      0.0      0.0
'''

# filtering by product
prod_A = g_data.loc[('A'),]

>>> prod_A
'''
month     2021-10  2021-11  2021-12
customer                           
eric.       213.0      0.0      0.0
harry         0.0    210.0      0.0
sam           0.0    221.0      0.0
tim           0.0      0.0    220.0
```

Comment: getting key error

Comment: i think there is issue in column names

Comment: can you write a code to rename column names after the 1st output

Comment: can you write code change column names from multiindex to single

Comment: @tim83 just do `g_data.reset_index()`

Comment: not working !!!!